# Rewrite Rules inside httpd does not work

Tags: url-rewriting

I placed my rewrite rules inside directory tag.
Before I asked the question I've read Apache documentation where is written:

> A web-path to a resource
>
> > RewriteRule ^/foo$ /bar
>
> If DocumentRoot is set to /usr/local/apache2/htdocs, then this directive would map requests for http://example.com/foo to the path /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/bar.

So I did as written.
In example below I want: /aaaaa to redirect to /index.php?action=aaaaa

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/released/test

    <Directory /var/www/project/released/test>
            AllowOverride none
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all

            RewriteEngine on                
            RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)$     /index.php?action=$1 [NC,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In apache log is written:

```
[Mon May 27 23:14:11 2013] [error] File does not exist: /var/www/project/released/test/aaaaa
```

Could you please help and advice why this may not work and why the log shows totally different behavior (obviously this path does not exist but it never should, according to the doc!)? I have mod_rewrite installed and enabled.

Comment: Have you tried `<Directory />`? I'm not sure if the Directory is relative to the DocumentRoot in some cases when a DocumentRoot is specified.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense but still it does not work. The same error in logs

Comment: Forgive me. I guess this might work with the full Directory too (you could check that later if it's running). But there seems to be an error within you regex. Try `^([a-z0-9-_]+)$` (without the beginning `/`). Works for me at my test environment. I'll give up if it still fails for you ;-)

Comment: Lucky you, I've tried all methods: with absolute path and relative (/), plus slashes on the beginning and without them. All the times the same error message and 404 :(. Perhaps it is something wrong with the configuration of the server? But I didn't apply any advanced options...

Comment: SORRY IT WORKS, I don't know why. I always reset cache etc. But the final version which works is how you said. Full path, no slash on the beginning and slash next to index (/index.php...)